# MD5 with double randomized salt?

Tags: php, md5

I'm coding a CMS, but does this work?

```
MD5(MD5(username+password)+salt+rsalt);
```

The `rsalt` stands for Randomized salt but how can i randomize a salt anyway?

Comment: Use a [secure hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5235195/1557526) method instead of fiddling with `md5`!

Comment: If you do not know how to store passwords, you should not be "coding a CMS".

Comment: agreed with @kingkero -- MD5 is broken. Don't use it for passwords under any circumstances, not even with multiple hashes and salts. Use bcrypt instead.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can randomize the salt **if** you are storing said salt in the user's table. Otherwise, how will you be able to tell if the hash is correct?
2. MD5 is not a secure hash function. You should use something like [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) if you have PHP >= 5.5 or the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library by [**ircmaxell**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell) if you're using an earlier version.