# Issue with Hashing in PHP

Tags: php, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most secure hashing method? (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291862/what-is-the-most-secure-hashing-method-php)

I know that there is not a 100% secure hashing system in PHP but can you please let me now what is the best hashing available from following list or anything more in PHP ,right now?

```
<?php
 $password = ‘SomePassword!’;
 echo ‘md5: ‘ . hash(‘md5’, $password) . ‘<br />’;
 echo ‘sha1: ‘ . hash(‘sha1’, $password) . ‘<br />’;
 echo ‘sha512: ‘ . hash(‘sha512’, $password) . ‘<br />’;
 echo ‘whirlpool: ‘ . hash(‘whirlpool’, $password) . ‘<br />’;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Definitely go for `bcrypt`. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: These are all general purpose hashing functions. None of them should be used when there are better ones like *crypt* and its derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

bCrypt is probably the best solution to go with at this point in time.